# syntax error in the file name when I run a python script twice?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ipython

When I try to use the `run` command twice in IPython, I get a syntax error the second time:

```
In [2]: run control.py

In [3]: run control.py
  File "<ipython-input-3-3e54b0f85f39>", line 1
    run control.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In my script I implemented a class and made an object from that class.

I tried to make a new python script without any classes and objects, and it works fine when I run it many times, why do classes and objects produce the problem?

I use ipython on Windows (NOT the notebook).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct ipython command is `%run`, with the `%` prefix. Without the prefix *can* work, but *only* if you don't also have a Python global name `run` masking the command.

Because `%run script.py` runs the script *inside the IPython interpreter*, any globals that script sets are available in the interpreter after the script has completed. And your `console.py` script set the global name `run`, and that name is now *masking* the `%run` command.

In other words, this has nothing to do with classes or instances. Either use `%run` to run the script, or don't use the name `run` anywhere in the script itself.

Demo using a little script setting `run`; note how `%run` continues to work, and how *deleting* the name `run` can also make `run demo.py` work again:

```
In [1]: %cat demo.py
print('Setting the name "run" to "foo"')
run = 'foo'

In [2]: run demo.py
Setting the name "run" to "foo"

In [3]: run  # the global name is set
Out[3]: 'foo'

In [4]: run demo.py
  File "<ipython-input-4-3c6930c3028c>", line 1
    run demo.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [5]: %run demo.py
Setting the name "run" to "foo"

In [6]: del run  # deleting the global name makes 'run script' work again

In [7]: run demo.py
Setting the name "run" to "foo"
```